# Arranging 5 people in 3 rooms. Max 3 per room

Tags: combinatorics

Arranging 5 people in 3 rooms.  Max 3 per room.

Take one person and put in any of the 3 rooms. Do this for all.

$(1\times 3C1)^5 = 243.$

That's all the ways without limit.
Then minus cases with 5 in one room and 4 in one room.

Take all 5 and put in any of the 3 rooms
$1*3C1 = 3.$

4 in one room:
Take 4 of 5 and put then in any room and then same for the lonely person.
$5C4 \times 3C1 \times 1 \times 3C1 = 45.$

Answer: $243-3-45= 195$.

Is this correct?

Comment: I think for your 4 in one room case, you need the lonely person to be in a different room from the group, so it should be $1\cdot 2C1$.

Comment: You have a right idea, however your calculation seems off for the 4 in one room case.  Walk through the numbers and remind yourself why you are using $5$ or $3$ etc at each point in the calculation.  So, you choose four of the five people to go in one of the rooms, and you pick which room that was.  You then take the remaining person and put that person *in a different room*.

Answer (score 1):

I want to give you different approach . As far as i have understood the rooms are distinguishable ,i.e , different from each other. So they will have maximum $3$ people and minimum $0$ people.

Then , we can use exponential generating functions. Lets write exponential generating function for each room such that $1+ x+ \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6}$.

So , we should find the coefficient of term $x^5$ in $(1+ x+ \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6})^3$.,and multiply it by $5!$ such that https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expanded+form+of+%281%2Bx%2B+x%5E2+%2F2+%2B+x%5E3+%2F6%29%5E3

We saw that the coefficient of $x^5$ is $\frac{7}{4}$ ,so $5! \times \frac{7}{4} =210$